# Java JFileChooser .png files to byte[] black image

Tags: java, image, byte, png

I need to upload an image .png to the server and show it to Swing GUI, I am using JFileChooser, the user selects a .png image and it gets stored on a byte[]. Later when I try to display the image, it is all in black. This don't happen with .jpg files. I have a problem with the transparency of .png images. This is my code:

Saving Image to byte[]:

```
public byte[] AvatarToByte(String url){
    byte[] data = null;
    String extension = "";
    try{            
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if(url.toString().toLowerCase().contains(".png")){
            extension = "png";
        }else{
            extension = "jpg";
        }
        ImageIO.write(bImage, extension, bos );
        data = bos.toByteArray();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

From byte[] to java swing:

```
public ByteToAvatar(byte[] data){
    BufferedImage img = null;                       
    img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

    JLabel lblURL = new JLabel();
    lblURL.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
    lblURL.setBackground(SystemColor.controlLtHighlight);
    lblURL.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 80);           
    lblURL.setIcon(Resize(img));
}
```

Resize:

```
private ImageIcon Resize(Image img){
    Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImg);
    return image;
}
```

edit: tried to display the image before resizing and it is shown correctly. There must be something wrong with Resize(Image img).

Comment: so do some troubleshooting - its not all pancakes - does it show before scaling? does it show when it comes out of the box?? do some work dont just ask questions

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works without problems.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class Test {
    static GraphicsConfiguration gc;
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        frame= new JFrame(gc);  
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        byte[] b=  AvatarToByte("e:/dog.png");
        ByteToAvatar(b);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static byte[] AvatarToByte(String url){
        byte[] data = null;
        String extension = "";
        try{            
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if(url.toString().toLowerCase().contains(".png")){
            extension = "png";
        }else{
            extension = "jpg";
        }
        ImageIO.write(bImage, extension, bos );
        data = bos.toByteArray();
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void ByteToAvatar(byte[] data) throws IOException{
        BufferedImage img = null;                       
        img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

        JLabel lblURL = new JLabel();
        lblURL.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        lblURL.setBackground(SystemColor.controlLtHighlight);
        lblURL.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 80);           
        lblURL.setIcon(Resize(img));

        frame.getContentPane().add(lblURL);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static ImageIcon Resize(Image img){
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        return image;
    }
}
```